# scala-maven-plugin makes scala-library disappear for Scala IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, m2e

`scala-maven-plugin` seems to make the `scala-library` dependency disappear from the `Maven Dependencies` in Scala IDE.

Minimal .pom to reproduce: http://pastebin.com/r4r6MeFn

Remove `scala-maven-plugin` and all is fine (except no Scala code gets compiled).

How do I compile Scala code with Maven **and** have the right `scala-library` show up in Scala IDE automatically?